# why should we use q.defer(); in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am learning node JS. I have read some articles but I can't find the proper answer.

Here is the syntax

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
let request = require('request');
let async = require('async');
let q = require('q');
let fs = require('fs');
let BC_STORE_URL = '*****************************';
let BC_USER = '********';
let BC_TOKEN = '******************************';

app.get('/api/:sku', function(req, res, next) {
   getData('products?sku=' + productSku).then((resData) => {
   });
})

let getData = function(storeField) {
    let listInfo = [];
    let deferred = q.defer();
    request(getDataOptions, (getDataOptionsError, getDataOptionsResponse, 
      getDataOptionsData) => {
        deferred.resolve(responseData);
      }
}
```

Comment: We shouldn't. Instead you can use native promise constructor. Or native promisify util

Answer (score 1):

The [q.defer()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) is used to create deferred which is used to work with promises. The promise will tell the caller that the method is returning some data in some time (async). The caller can then declare logic on the promise then() to be executed when the data is returned.

You should return a promise from the getData function to which the caller can use then()

```
  let getData = function(storeField) {
        let listInfo = [];
        let deferred = q.defer();
        request(getDataOptions, (getDataOptionsError, getDataOptionsResponse, 
          getDataOptionsData) => {
            deferred.resolve(responseData);
          }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's better explanation to your answer : 
[Q vs native promises](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/03/second-look-at-promises-native-es6.html)